# 'ERROR_MALFORMED_TOKEN' in next.js with Graphql using hasura

Tags: next.js, graphql, hasura

This is my code in login api in next.js :
Login.js file -

```
import { magicAdmin } from "../../lib/magic";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export default async function login(req, res) {
if (req.method === "POST") {
 try {
   const auth = req.headers.authorization;
   const didToken = auth ? auth.substr(7) : "";
   console.log({ didToken });
   const metadata = await magicAdmin.users.getMetadataByToken(didToken);
   console.log({ metadata });
   const token = jwt.sign(
     {
       ...metadata,
       iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
       exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000 + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60),
       "https://hasura.io/jwt/claims": {
         "x-hasura-allowed-roles": ["user", "admin"],
         "x-hasura-default-role": "user",
         "x-hasura-user-id": `${metadata.issuer}`,
       },
     },
     "thisisasecretthisisasecret4445822"
   );
   console.log("generate", token);
   res.send({ done: true });
 } catch (error) {
   console.error(error);
   res.status(500).send({ done: false });
 }
} else {
 res.send({ done: false });
}
}
```

when i send POST request using thunderclient it is giving me this error :

```
{ didToken: 'token1' }
MagicAdminSDKError: Magic Admin SDK Error: [ERROR_MALFORMED_TOKEN] The DID token is malformed or failed to parse.
    at new MagicAdminSDKError (/home/jinalkhatri/Documents/Next Tutorials/netflix/node_modules/@magic-sdk/admin/dist/core/sdk-exceptions.js:22:28)
    at Object.createMalformedTokenError (/home/jinalkhatri/Documents/Next Tutorials/netflix/node_modules/@magic-sdk/admin/dist/core/sdk-exceptions.js:54:12)
    at Object.parseDIDToken (/home/jinalkhatri/Documents/Next Tutorials/netflix/node_modules/@magic-sdk/admin/dist/utils/parse-didt.js:33:32)
    at TokenModule.decode (/home/jinalkhatri/Documents/Next Tutorials/netflix/node_modules/@magic-sdk/admin/dist/modules/token/index.js:86:40)
    at TokenModule.getIssuer (/home/jinalkhatri/Documents/Next Tutorials/netflix/node_modules/@magic-sdk/admin/dist/modules/token/index.js:95:21)
    at UsersModule.<anonymous> (/home/jinalkhatri/Documents/Next Tutorials/netflix/node_modules/@magic-sdk/admin/dist/modules/users/index.js:137:41)
    at step (/home/jinalkhatri/Documents/Next Tutorials/netflix/node_modules/@magic-sdk/admin/dist/modules/users/index.js:46:23)
    at Object.next (/home/jinalkhatri/Documents/Next Tutorials/netflix/node_modules/@magic-sdk/admin/dist/modules/users/index.js:27:53)
    at /home/jinalkhatri/Documents/Next Tutorials/netflix/node_modules/@magic-sdk/admin/dist/modules/users/index.js:21:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>) {
  code: 'ERROR_MALFORMED_TOKEN',
  data: []
}
```

i have added this as token in Bearer token field of Thunderclient :
token12wert

This is magic.js file :

```
import { Magic } from "@magic-sdk/admin";
export const magicAdmin = new Magic(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAGIC_SERVER_KEY);
```

Comment: why do you want the double quotes? they are not required - for an object property name, both pieces of code are identical

Comment: when creating jwt i am getting error, that ERROR_TOKEN_MALFORMED, so i think the reason for error is that quotes.that's why i want the quotes

Comment: no ... it isn't the reason

Comment: so, if i add  the new question with the error, then can you help me with that?

Comment: this question is fine ... change the question, show what `metadata` is - describe what is throwing that error

Comment: ok let me update the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246986/discussion-between-front-dev-j-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: what code is throwing that error?

Comment: looks like `magicAdmin.users.getMetadataByToken(didToken);` is the issue

Comment: not able to find, what's wrong with it, can you please help?

Comment: since `magicAdmin` is **your* code, and you haven't posted it, I'd say the answer is a pineapple

Comment: I have added the file from which magicAdmin is imported , so please have a look, and if you require anything other than that file, then please comment but please help i am stuck on this problem very badly

Comment: just debug the issue - clearly something is "going wrong"

Comment: i am beginner ,currently learning it, i tried to debug as much as i can, but not able to find, what is wrong

Comment: well, I don't have a magic.link account so I have no access to the documentation that explains how to use `magicAdmin`  - and I'm not going to sign up just to read the documentation for you - clearly your `didToken` is malformed/invalid - which could mean any number of things

Comment: okay, thanks for guiding, it helped a lot, i found the issue. Thanks for help.

Comment: i can understand, no one is free to help for every small problem, everyone have their priorities.

Answer (score 0):

The Bearer token which i was passing in the Thunderclient was wrong.

This is how i got the correct token :

```
import { magic } from "../../lib/magic-client";

const didToken = await magic.user.getIdToken();
console.log({didtoken});
```

and then passed this into the Thunderclient as Bearer Token, and it solved the issue.